# meaning of the word "trigger" in context?

Tags: meaning

It is from the online journal [*Psychology Today*](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/life-refracted/201802/7-reasons-committed-lover-cheats?utm_source=FacebookPost&utm_medium=FBPost&utm_campaign=FBPost). Here it goes:

> Some of those behaviors can become habitual — i.e., habits. The resulting chain — **trigger** activating motive, leading to behavior, leading to repetition, which eventually leads to habit, a specific style of responding — follows the social learning theory traced by Julian Rotter in the 1950s.

I cannot get what  *trigger activating motive* is. If the word *trigger* was used there as a verb then why was that used in the infinitive form? Should not it be *triggers* *activating* *motive*? And Why was the definite article was omitted before the word motive? Could you please rephrase the whole sentence for me?

Answer (score 1):

[Trigger](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/trigger) is a noun here, the activating motive is a trigger that will lead to repetition which will lead to habit etc.

> [ C usually singular ] an event or situation, etc. that causes something to start.